# Почему не работает тест в Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, тестирование, rspec

Почему не срабатывает тест?

```
   require 'rspec'
class Test 
  attr_accessor :name  
  def girl
    puts "Hello #{name}"
  end
end

describe "Hello" do
 it "Hello Mari" do
 name1=Test.new
 name1.name="Mari"
 name1.girl=="Hello Mari"
 end

end
```

Answer (score -1):

Новичкам можно порекомендовать почаще обращаться к документации http://rspec.info

А не работает потому, что что тесты пишут немного иначе

```
name1 = Test.new
name1.name = 'Mari'
expect(name1.girl).to eq('Hello Mari')
```

Comment: Согласен, но пока найдешь конкретный там ответ, пройдет много времени, а так я вам благодарен за ответ.

Comment: [здесь](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames) много примеров

Comment: Ваш код тоже не работает, я его проверял(

Comment: Вот ошибка кода Hello Mari
F

Failures:

  1) Hello Hello Mari
     Failure/Error: expect(name1.girl).to eq("Hello Mari")

       expected: "Hello Mari"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./ww.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.04207 seconds (files took 0.34031 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./ww.rb:11 # Hello Hello Mari

Comment: не заметил в вашем методе используется `puts`. Для того, чтобы вернуть строку можно написать просто `"Hello #{name}"` (без puts). А если хотите тестировать именно стандартный вывод то может помочь эта ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709317/how-to-test-puts-in-rspec/30342935

Comment: не работает ( require "rspec"
 class A
 attr_accessor :name
  def name1
  puts "Hello #{@name}"
 end
end

describe "Hello" do
 it "Hello Mari" do
 name3=A.new
 name3.name="Mari"
 expect(name3.name1).to output("Hello Mari") 
 end 
end